# how to import the jdbc driver for sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc

Can any one support me? I have an issue trying to import the JDBC driver  JAR in Eclipse Oxygen JRE8 for SQL Server 2017.

I have downloaded JDBC driver 6.4 and 4.2. Driver are added in library by build path, but I have error in my code which means this JAR could not import this:

```
Class.forName("com.sqlserver.jdbc.driver")
```

Comment: Please post a snippet of the offending code.

Comment: In the Eclipse Data Source Explorer you there's an icon (that looks like a small blue triangle) when creating a new connection where you can specify the *.jar file(s) to use as the JDBC driver. It's a small icon you need to click on. You already downloaded the `db2jcc4.jar`, right?

Comment: @TheImpaler What does db2jcc4.jar have to do with SQL Server? That driver is for DB2.